# Do 3-way switches burn out?

Tags: lighting, switch

I have a light (that is on two three-way switches. 1 AT top of stairs, 1 at bottom.  It has worked for years.) the light burned out.  I replaced it and the new one did not work, either.  I checked the voltage coming out of one of the three-way switches and whether turned up or down, I get 125 v on three wires.  Can a 3 way switch "wear-out" after a period of time?

Comment: It is usually a very long time for normal use.  It does shorten if someone spends eight hours a day flipping the switches.  It does sound like there is a problem and replacement is needed, but I am no expert on three ways.  You do want to take pictures and label wires before removing them.  With the breaker off.  Three ways are confusing if you do not know the wires.

Comment: Describe how you determine there's "125V on three wires". Likely you have meaningless results from a no-contact "voltage tester". That said, there's nothing about 3-ways that would make them more or less prone to "burning out" than any other switch.

Comment: Loose "back stab" connections are a likely culprit for this. They make wiring quick and easy - you just strip the wire and stab it into a little hole in the back of the switch. However, they don't hold very well and rely on a small brass flap to hold the wire in place and make the electrical connection. Eventually the brass flap fails to hold and this is what happens. Spend an extra dollar or two on a "spec grade" replacement switch then stick the bare wire into the clamp & properly torque it. Significantly lower chance of this happening in the future.

Answer (score 6):

Three-way switches are mechanical devices as well as electrical. They don't normally burn out, but they can wear out, just as simple switches can.

Exception: "Backstab" connections do have a history of failing, sometimes generating a lot of heat in the process. That's certainly part of the switch unit, even if not the actual switch mechanism.

Comment: You know......the common screw was not used (all the others were) but the wiring was done by pushing the wire into the hole........you may be right!  Thanks

Comment: I'm also confused -- "Common screw"? There's no "common" in house wiring, at least in US terminology. Hot(s), switched hot(s), neutral, safety ground.